# Resetting Recaptcha in Rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, recaptcha

I've got a hand rolled registration form where I am using the [Ambethia Recaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha). Everything works fine when the form is valid. However, when it is not, I need the ReCaptcha to be reset. Here is the create method:

```
def create
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.create(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if verify_recaptcha(model: @user, timeout: 300, message: "Problem with ReCAPTCHA, please try again.") && @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you for signing up!"
        format.html 
        format.js {render js: "window.location = '#{root_path}';"}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }

        if Rails.env.production?
          UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Sign Up Failed!"
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

You see, when the form is correct, the ReCaptcha works, but when there is a validation failure, like passwords not matching, The Recaptcha shows up already checked. Then when you correct the validation errors, you can't redo the ReCaptcha and you get the "Problem with ReCAPTCHA..." error. This is the form that contains my `recaptcha_tags`:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="spinner">
    <%= image_tag "loading.gif" %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="registration-form">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <%= form_for @user, remote: true, html: { style: "display:inline;" } do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="errors"></ul>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br>
            <%= f.email_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter a valid email" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :username, 'Username' %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :username, required: true, placeholder: "Pick a username" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password, required: true, placeholder: "Create a password" %>
            <p id="form-tip">Passwords must be at least <strong>8 characters</strong> in length and contain at least <strong>one upper case letter</strong>, <strong>one lower case letter</strong>, and <strong>one number or special character</strong>.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true, placeholder: "Password again" %>
          </div>

          <%= render 'recaptcha' %>

          <div class="modal-footer actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-l btn-success"%>
            <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn btn-l btn-danger", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This form is rendered with an AJAX request from a navbar button. Form submission triggers the following *_save.js.erb*:

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    $("#new_user_modal").modal("hide")
<% end %>
```

I have tried to add `$(".g-recaptcha").grecaptcha.reset();` to make the recaptcha reload. I've tried lots of things. Nothing seems to work. **When my form is reloaded with the validation errors, a new ReCAPTCHA box should appear.** Either that or somehow allow the user to fix their errors and continue without redoing the recaptcha.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following code, which will bind (via jquery) to the ajax:error thrown by your JSON return / 422.

```
$('#registration-form form').on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
  if (window.grecaptcha) grecaptcha.reset();
})
```

The simplest way, using something like jQuery would be to bind to your form element, and handle it on error.  When your remote call returns, you can simply reset the form, but only on error.  This way you can ensure your users will always get a fresh reCaptcha form and once again validate.  This seems to be part of the RAILS gem as I hit the same piece tonight and solved it using that.

Answer (score 1):

So nobody has responded, but I have found a way around the problem for now. I still can't seem to "reset" the ReCaptcha, but by removing the "optional" parameters from the `verify_recaptcha` method in the controller it no longer expects the user to resubmit a new recaptcha. Mainly it's the un-binding of ReCaptcha to the User model that allows it to "bypass" the model validation. I updated this line in **users_controller.rb**:

```
...
if verify_recaptcha(model: @user, timeout: 300, message: "Problem with ReCAPTCHA, please try again.") && @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
...
```

to this:

```
...
if verify_recaptcha && @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
...
```

Still interested to know how to go about *actually resetting* the ReCaptcha (preferably via the gem itself or a jQuery call). I've thrown everything at it (clearing the div, toggling classes, `g-recaptcha.reset()` function, messing with the `timeout` attribute, etc...) and nothing has worked.

Big thanks to anyone who can help!